# Why don't Multi-dimensional (non-numpy) list slices work (anymore?)

Tags: python, list, slice

### Didn't we used to...

I remember being able to type in something like

```py
>>> mylist = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> myslice = slice(1,3)
>>> mylist[myslice, myslice]
```

and getting back something like

```
[[5, 6], [8, 9]]
```

---

If I type the code above, I will get the following error (in Python 3.7):

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

But if I call just one dimension, it works fine:

```py
>>> mylist[myslice]
[[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

---

### What's the Direct, Easy Slice Syntax?

While I'm mildly interested if things changed or if I am just going crazy, I *mostly* want to know how I can do multi-dimensional slicing.  What is the correct syntax instead of

```
>>> mylist[myslice, myslice]
```

or

```
>>> mylist[myslice][myslice]
```

?  (The second one does not raise an error, but it does not work.  It returns `[7, 8, 9]`.)

I know I can do list comprehensions, use `numpy`, or other "workarounds".  But how can a slice  be used directly for multiple dimensions?  If I want just one element, the syntax works fine:

```
>>> mylist[1][1]
```

But this will not work for slices...

Comment: "Didn't we used to..."—No, I don't think we did. Not in plain Python.

Comment: You can't use multiple slices like `list[1:3, 1:3]` in plain Python. Are you using numpy arrays? That's numpy syntax.

Comment: You might be confusing plain python arrays with numpy arrays.

Comment: Yes, I might be confusing with `numpy`.  This lack of multi-dimensionality **really** limits the utility of the `slice` paradigm. Using a list comprehension seems like a "if the only tool you have is a hammer then everything looks like a nail" solution.  Oh well...

Comment: If you can use numpy, make an array and then your slice operations should work: `mylist = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this in plain python is by using a list comprehension:

```
myslice = slice(1,3)
mylist = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
sliced = [partSlice[myslice] for partSlice in mylist[myslice]]
print(sliced)
```

Output:

```
[[5, 6], [8, 9]]
```

Try it [here](https://tio.run/##PYy9DoMgFIV3nuKMmtzFotUOfQpHcgejbUqiQJCFp0eRxun85JzPxfCzRqa0xX3V8wdvXFo1JGuxxVXv4eyUaggPgmSCagkd4ZltTxgIL2ZxvZY8dZMPY07qz2R8rcddQxsU8D1g4bw2oSqQOqUD).

Comment: Yes, I know you are correct, and I knew this method.  I just figured there must be an easier way, and I thought there was one.  But as @meto mentioned, I must have mis-remembered and used `numpy` in the past.